# RWD - elements with width 100% overspilling

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a mobile version of my site, but any element with width: 100% and padding keeps spilling over my container section. I understand this is because child element is getting wider than the container of a padding value, but how can I keep them full width but with keeping some padding on the left within the child element (so the text doesn't stick to the browser's window)?

Simple code:

```
section#main {
    padding: 100px 0 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
  input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Results in:

http://tinypic.com/r/2ytxjk9/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is you are basically saying, 100% wide but add 100px padding. The easiest fix is to alter the `box-sizing: border-box` CSS3 Property. This will make it 100% wide including 100px padding.

Comment: How about IE8 compatibility?

Comment: Ok, I've checked it, it works in IE8 too. Thanks for your help man